# Which CI server works with SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm considering using SBT for a new scala project, but I'm not sure which CI server - hudson / cruise / whatever has support for it. Any ideas?

I know SBT is a little Maven like, but I don't think it can work as a drop in replacement for Maven in the eyes of a CI server.

Answer (score 1):

By now you would have worked through this. But I found simple integration possible by getting Hudson to call a bash script that invoked SBT. I didn't do any further integration. The solution was able to trigger a build and show the output. That is all I needed at the time.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Travis CI https://travis-ci.org works great with SBT. See http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/scala/ for details on using them together.

Some of my own SBT-based projects on Travis:

- https://travis-ci.org/SethTisue/lens-examples
- https://travis-ci.org/NetLogo/NetLogo-Headless
- https://travis-ci.org/NetLogo/Tortoise